# Running parametrized neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j

Given below is the cypher query which gets repeated for each relationship type as mentioned in parameterized list and each relationship type has specific property and value to be added to the connecting node. According the neo4j, it is not possible to parametrize relationship type. Is there anyway to address this using cypher? or with apoc?

```
Merge(n_device: Device{identifier: {deviceId}}) ON CREATE SET n_device.created=timestamp()
WITH n_device
OPTIONAL MATCH (n_device)-[r_prev:{deviceRel}{active:true}]->() 
WITH n_device, r_prev   
Merge(n_deviceOs: Device{{deviceRelProp}: {deviceRelPropVal}}) ON CREATE SET n_deviceOs :DeviceOs,  n_deviceOs.created=timestamp(), n_deviceOs.newNode=true
WITH n_device, n_deviceOs, r_prev
Merge (n_device)-[r_cur:{deviceRel}]->(n_deviceOs) ON CREATE SET r_cur.active=true, r_cur.created=timestamp()
WITH n_deviceOs, r_prev
Match(n_deviceOs) where n_deviceOs.newNode=true set r_prev.active = false, r_prev.modified=timestamp()
REMOVE n_deviceOs.newNode

"params": {
    "deviceId": "1234",
    "deviceRel": ["HAS_DEVICE_OS", "HAS_DEVICE_OSINFO", "HAS_DEVICE_MODEL", "HAS_DEVICE_APPVERSION"],
    "deviceRelProp": ["os", "osinfo", "model", "version"],
    "deviceRelPropVal": ["android", "kitkat", "samsung", "1.64.2"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j can't create a relationship with a parameterized type. But there is an APOC Procedure which allows this. See the [creating data section](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data), apoc.create.relationship() is the procedure you're looking for.

Comment: I see its for creating the relationship. If you see the above query, i also need one for matching the node-relationship-node. I don't see one in apoc for it.

Comment: `MATCH (n_device)-[r_prev{active:true}]->() WHERE TYPE(r_prev) = {deviceRel}` (or the same filter for your second match) can do it in native Cypher.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the approach as you mentioned. Is it possible to send a list and parametrize the query for each value of the list? If neo4j doesn't support readily, is it possible to do apoc?